# How to do an upsert when updating a table from another table postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `A` that contains about 10 millions rows and Table `B` which contains some updated information for some rows in table `A` and also contains new rows that don't exist in table `A`.

I want to update table `A` using table `B` and at the same time insert rows that have no match in table`A`.

I found many answers like the solution below but it seems like they all miss the inserting part that I'm looking for.

```
UPDATE A 
SET code = B.code
FROM B
WHERE A.id = B.id
```

Comment: If the data is in two tables, just run two queries, an `update` and an `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two queries:

```
update a
    set code = b.code
    from b
    where a.id = b.id;

insert into a (id, code)
    select id, code
    from b
    where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id);
```

You can also use `on conflict`

```
insert into a (id, code)
    select b.id, b.code
    on conflict on constraint a_id
    do update set code = b.code;
```